# Custom filtering in range in meteor with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, filtering, angular-meteor

I have a big problem with filtering by range. 
I need to filter products by price. Sorry for the mess

HTML:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="cena.minAmount">
<input type="number" ng-model="cena.maxAmount">

<div ng-repeat="przedmiot in przedmioty | filterPrice">
    <p>
      {{przedmiot.name}}
    </p>
    <p>
      {{przedmiot.cena | currency}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
this.amountRange = function(input, cena) {
  var filteredAmount = [];
  angular.forEach(input, function(przedmiot){
    if(amount && (przedmiot.cena >= cena.minAmount && przedmiot.cena        <=  cena.maxAmount))
    filteredAmount.push(item);
  });
  return filteredAmount.length>0 ? filteredAmount : input
  }`
```

Comment: Do you want to get filtered results also from the server? from the Mongo DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS has currency filter, you can check these examples a bit more:

[AngularJS www.w3schools.com currency Filter](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_currency.asp)

[AngularJS docs currency Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

You have to create your custom filter:

[Building custom filters](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters)

Comment: Thanks, but I mean filtering by range of numbers in set in input fields. Like in search box in ecommerce, when you want to search for products between 20$ and 50$.